# Python dynamic loop termination variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I want below piece of code to append 2's to the list 'a' until it gets the size of ten. However, it doesn't work in the way I wish. What am I missing?

```
a = [1,2]

for ctr in range(0,len(a)):
    print ctr
    if len(a) < 10:
        a.append(2)
```

Comment: The for loop seems to be a bit short, doesn't it? And even if it would've been evaluated each time, it's not very readable.

Comment: My main concern here was not implementing a for loop doing a silly job as above but understand how it works and how it differs from while loop in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only loop twice; the `len(a)` is *only* evaluated to create the `range()`, not on every iteration of the loop. Thus, you only end up with a list of length 4.

Use a `while` statement instead:

```
while len(a) < 10:
    a.append(2)
```

or `.extend()` with the correct number of `2`s:

```
a.extend([2] * (10 - len(a)))
```

or use `+=` (which is short-hand for `.extend()`):

```
a += [2] * (10 - len(a))
```

Both of these approaches avoid loops altogether.

Answer (score 3):

`range(len(a))` is evaluated once, when the loop begins. At this point, your list has two items, so the loop will be executed exactly twice.

To do what you want, a better approach would be:

```
a += [2] * (10 - len(a))
```

You know how many items you wish to add, so add them all at once, rather than adding them one at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a while loop until its the size you want:

```
a = [1,2]
while len(a) < 10:
    a.append(2)
```

The problem is that you were basing your original loop on the current size of `a`. When it evaluates, it will only loop 2 times. A `while` loop on the other hand is going to keep evaluating that length each time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in another approach for completeness... (and may be more flexible about padding out values from other iterables etc...)

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice, repeat
>>> list(islice(chain(a, repeat(2)), 10))
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```